# Drupal 7 Corporate Clean Theme - Social Media

Tags: drupal, icons, social-media

I noticed that drupal Corporate Clean theme comes with most of the social media icons.  These icons are included in the images folder.

Is there a setting in admin configuration to display these icons?  How can I use these icons?  I figure that since these icons are included, there should be a configuration to use them.  Or do I need to add some code in php to display them?

Here's a demo site using Corporate Clean theme. Scroll to the bottom where these icons are being used.  I would like to have something like this.

http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=corporateclean

Comment: With the code that I can see, they are blocks in footer. You need to add blocks through your Drupal admin panel for the footer icons.

Comment: So which blocks for the footer icon? I don't see any blocks that pertain to these icons. I am using drupal 7 with corporate theme 7.x-2.3

Comment: Got it. Just added new block and add code to show these icons. Thanks